# Bash script using "ldapscripts" package does not work from cron

Tags: bash, cron, ldap, file-descriptor, cron-task

`Prerequisite: ldapscripts package, Version: 2.0.1-1`

`uname output: Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: This question uses `ldapid` which is one of the many scripts part of the `ldapscripts` package. This behaviour can be replicated with any of the scripts from this package.

Consider the following two line bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ldapid
```

This works fine when run from the shell. As soon as it is made a cron job, the error message `Could not guess user` is thrown.

I had a similar problem earlier, consider the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
ldapid    
while read line    
do
  ldapid
done <"Some file"
```

The first ldapid always worked but the second one threw the same error `Could not guess user`.

This eventually turned out to be a file descriptor problem and was solved by using the following snippet:

```
while read line <&3
do
  ldapid
done 3< "Some file"
```

With cron, I do not know how to do something similar for a lack of better understanding and any help will be much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

------------Edit with more details, after PiratStian's responses -----------------

Sorry if I should have said this earlier, only wanted to keep it simple so that it could be replicated easily. The form

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ldap<script> $user
```

is what I have in my rather long script. The exact command, right at the beginning of my script and where the whole thing fails with the error `cannot guess user` is  `description=$(ldapfinger "$user" |grep description |cut -d: -f2)`  with $user defined one line before. Replacing $user with a harcoded `username` does not help either.

Seems that any input, implicitly or explicity passed as a parameter, is just ignored when run as a cron job with the error `Cannot guess user`. On the other hand, when I manually run the same script, everything works as intended. (And note, this was a working script before some update with ldapscripts).

At the risk of sounding stupid, I also tried running the command with `bash -c` inside the script and also using `* * * * * root /path/to/script.sh<&0` in crontab with the same results, `Cannot guess user`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got analogous issue under Debian Wheezy (Linux earth 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 i686 GNU/Linux)

In order to get ldapscripts working I've done some changes in contents of '/usr/share/ldapscripts/runtime'.
Instead of line:

```
   USER=$(logname 2>/dev/null)
```

I've just used

```
   USER=$(whoami 2>/dev/null)
```

because I've found it is used mostly for logging (but I was not very strict in checkings).

That assignment was just one line above the fragment shown in previous post. Solution of the above post does not work because environment variable is ignored in that script.

There was yet one problem with that package regarding scripts like ldapaddgroup caused by unability to perform action. My problem was in fact ldapscripts package by default uses settings of libnss-ldap and libpam-ldap( which was not true in my case because I've installed libnss-ldap**d** and libpam-krb5). So I've performed manual configuration of /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.conf and all scripts I've tried ever are working

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the script is dependent on the ${USER} variable usually offered by shells?

Checking /usr/sbin/ldapid you find:

```
 # Current user
  [ -z "$USER" ] && end_die 'Could not guess current user (no $USER variable set)'
  _USER="$USER"
else
  _USER="$2"
```

Try something like: `* * * * * USER=myuser ldapid`

Or since you are running from a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=$(/usr/bin/whoami)
/usr/sbin/ldapid
```

Or the following (as it seems like ldapid accepts user as first argument

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/ldapid username
```

Comment: The script is run as root and when I try `* * * * * env USER=root /path/to/script.sh`, the script is not even executed. The crontab entry that I had before: `* * * * * root /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: Ah, try without env. Simply:
`* * * * * USER=root /path/to/script.sh`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I did that too, same result.

Comment: Updated the question in response to your updated answer since it might be easier to read.. thanks for sticking by PiratStian.